# BitmapData from LockBits consuming memory

Tags: c#, .net, bitmap, gdi+

I have a C# routine to take a YUV422 bitmap and convert to RGB:

```
    private unsafe void YUV422toRGB(byte[] YUV422, int YUVstride, ref Bitmap RGB)
    {
        //Found http://pastebin.com/MFsDnUCq after I wrote this.

        int row, col, index;
        byte y1, y2, u, v;
        int r1, r2, g1, g2, b1, b2;
        int c1, c2, d, e;
        byte* RGBbytes;
        int RGBindex;

        //http://bobpowell.net/lockingbits.aspx
        //It looks as though this bmp guy is consuming memory to the point
        //where I must force the garbage collector or the program will crash.
        //Why?
        System.Drawing.Imaging.BitmapData bmp =
            RGB.LockBits(
            new Rectangle(0, 0, RGB.Width, RGB.Height),
            System.Drawing.Imaging.ImageLockMode.WriteOnly,
            RGB.PixelFormat);
        RGBbytes = (byte*)bmp.Scan0;
        RGBindex = 0;
        index = 0;
        for (row = 0; row < RGB.Height; row++)
        {
            for (col = 0; col < YUVstride; col += 4)
            {
                u = YUV422[index + 0];
                y1 = YUV422[index + 1];
                v = YUV422[index + 2];
                y2 = YUV422[index + 3];
                index += 4;

                c1 = y1 - 16;
                c2 = y2 - 16;
                d = u - 128;
                e = v - 128;

                int c298 = 298 * c1;
                r1 = (c298 + 409 * e + 128) >> 8;
                g1 = (c298 - 100 * d - 208 * e + 128) >> 8;
                b1 = (c298 + 516 * d + 128) >> 8;

                c298 = 298 * c2;
                r2 = (c298 + 409 * e + 128) >> 8;
                g2 = (c298 - 100 * d - 208 * e + 128) >> 8;
                b2 = (c298 + 516 * d + 128) >> 8;

                //Now for clamping.
                //From http://graphics.stanford.edu/~seander/bithacks.html#IntegerMinOrMax
                //min(x, y) = y ^ ((x ^ y) & -(x < y))
                //max(x, y) = x ^ ((x ^ y) & -(x < y))
                //We want min(x, 255) followed by max(x, 0).
                //The problem is that x < y in C# is a bool which cannot be converted to int.
                //But effectively, -(x < y) is -1 if x < y and 0 otherwise.
                //we can do this by looking at the first bit of x-y
                //min(x, y) = y ^ ((x ^ y) & ((x - y) >> 31))
                //max(x, y) = x ^ ((x ^ y) & ((x - y) >> 31))
                //There appears to be 10% or so speed increase with the bithack.

                //r1 = Math.Max(0, Math.Min(r1, 255));
                //r2 = Math.Max(0, Math.Min(r2, 255));
                //g1 = Math.Max(0, Math.Min(g1, 255));
                //g2 = Math.Max(0, Math.Min(g2, 255));
                //b1 = Math.Max(0, Math.Min(b1, 255));
                //b2 = Math.Max(0, Math.Min(b2, 255));

                r1 = 255 ^ ((r1 ^ 255) & ((r1 - 255) >> 31));
                g1 = 255 ^ ((g1 ^ 255) & ((g1 - 255) >> 31));
                b1 = 255 ^ ((b1 ^ 255) & ((b1 - 255) >> 31));
                r2 = 255 ^ ((r2 ^ 255) & ((r2 - 255) >> 31));
                g2 = 255 ^ ((g2 ^ 255) & ((g2 - 255) >> 31));
                b2 = 255 ^ ((b2 ^ 255) & ((b2 - 255) >> 31));

                r1 = r1 ^ ((r1 ^ 0) & ((r1 - 0) >> 31));
                g1 = g1 ^ ((g1 ^ 0) & ((g1 - 0) >> 31));
                b1 = b1 ^ ((b1 ^ 0) & ((b1 - 0) >> 31));
                r2 = r2 ^ ((r2 ^ 0) & ((r2 - 0) >> 31));
                g2 = g2 ^ ((g2 ^ 0) & ((g2 - 0) >> 31));
                b2 = b2 ^ ((b2 ^ 0) & ((b2 - 0) >> 31));

                RGBbytes[RGBindex + 0] = (byte)b1;
                RGBbytes[RGBindex + 1] = (byte)g1;
                RGBbytes[RGBindex + 2] = (byte)r1;

                RGBbytes[RGBindex + 3] = (byte)b2;
                RGBbytes[RGBindex + 4] = (byte)g2;
                RGBbytes[RGBindex + 5] = (byte)r2;

                RGBindex += 6;
            }
        }

        RGB.UnlockBits(bmp);
    }
```

After the classic "hey, why does my program always crash after 30 seconds" I realized the garbage collector wasn't keeping up (I call this function 10 times a second, and the bitmaps are passed by reference throughout).

Stepping through the code I saw that `RGB.LockBits` was the one increasing the RAM usage. I added a `GC.Collect()` every ten calls (once per second) and now things are fine.

Am I doing something wrong here? Shouldn't `UnlockBits` clean up after itself?

Comment: I'm doing very similar computations and I never observed this behavior. How big are your bitmaps?

Comment: Are you running it with the debugger detached in release mode?

Comment: Consuming memory is LockBits() intention.  The real bug in your program is the missing Dispose() calls on the bitmaps.  And yes, GC.Collect() covers up your mistake.  It is the sledge-hammer solution.

Comment: @ScottChamberlain: No, running in debug mode.

Comment: @HansPassant: Negatory. I'm reusing the bitmaps and the same program has an interface to a different camera with the same "bitmap reuse" methodology and that one does not have memory creep issues.

Comment: We should be able to reproduce this if you can give us the values of YUV422 and YUVstride, and an url to the image you're using. I am unable to reproduce this when using a simple tight loop only locking/unlocking data.

Comment: @SimonSvensson: Let me create a simple program that replicates this so I can upload the whole thing.

Comment: @HansPassant: If I had a penny for every "profiler" I wasn't recommended by name....

Comment: @hansPassant - you were right about the undisposed bitmap. See my answer.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Hans Passant was correct. The issue was a bitmap that was being duplicated, though it's still not clear to me why this was causing the garbage collector to apparently fail to do its job.

I have some back-end classes in this program which take images from cameras and convert the bitmaps to the appropriate format (for example, the YUV422 to RGB conversion I posted). The bitmap that gets passed around is reused.

Then I have some UI classes, one of which is a window which displays a fresh frame on a timer running at more or less 10 Hz. Here you *must* copy the Bitmap since the back end stuff will be replacing it with a new frame, etc.

The routine to update the display was simple:

```
    public void SetImage(Bitmap Image)
    {
        if (this.IsDisposed) return;
        if (this.InvokeRequired)
            this.Invoke((MethodInvoker)delegate { SetImage(Image); });
        else
            picFrame.Image = (Bitmap)Image.Clone();
    }
```

One camera gives 640x480x8 bit (black and white) images; on the back end I also use lockbits to copy the array of pixels I get from the API calls to a .NET bitmap. I had no issues with memory even with two of these cameras (and display windows) running at once.

The 1920x1080 YUV422 image was obviously "saturating" (or however you'd call it) the garbage collector so that this version of the display routine fixed the problem:

```
    private Bitmap DisplayImage = null;
    public void SetImage(Bitmap Image)
    {
        if (this.IsDisposed) return;
        if (this.InvokeRequired)
            this.Invoke((MethodInvoker)delegate { SetImage(Image); });
        else
        {
            if (DisplayImage != null)
                DisplayImage.Dispose();
            DisplayImage = (Bitmap)Image.Clone();
            picFrame.Image = DisplayImage;
        }
    }
```

What threw me is that watching the memory usage with the black and white cameras only revealed it was nailed around some low number, while the color camera alone was skyrocketing toward 2 GB with no signs of stopping. I've seen borderline garbage collector cases where you see the memory creep up and then suddenly come back down when the garbage collector kicks in.

The clear difference here is of course that even two black and white cameras are only 614kB x 10 fps, whereas the color camera is some 10 times that. I am not even going to begin to conjecture why the former had no issues with the garbage collector and the latter did.

Comment: It is simpler to use `if (picFrame.Image != null) picFrame.Image.Dispose();` before the assignment.  Your "former" had issues too, you just didn't notice it because the garbage collector runs frequently enough to get the bitmap finalizer to clean up for you.  It ran "heavy", consuming lots of unmanaged memory unnecessarily.  Make the bitmap bigger and you'll run out of unmanaged memory before the finalizer gets a chance.

Answer (score 0):

> Stepping through the code I saw that RGB.LockBits was the one increasing the RAM usage. I added a GC.Collect() every ten calls (once per second) and now things are fine.

What you're saying is basically that a normal garbage collection will reclaim everything, and the issue is that the garbage collector isn't executed when you expect it to.

Are your machine low on memory? Do you have an actual memory pressure present that would force the garbage collector to trigger and reclaim space? Or do you have several gigabyte of free memory, so much that it's just a waste of cpu resource to pause all your threads to reclaim memory? It sounds like your machine just shrugs and says "Eh, I've got a lot more memory over here. Business as usual."

Comment: I have 32 GB of RAM (Windows 7 x64) but the program is x86, so it dies when it reaches 2 GB.